# What is the recommended way to use a shared View in a template which needs a controller

Tags: ember.js

We are using one of the later versions of Ember (router V2), not the bleeding edge with the even newer Router V2.2 (Last commit: 668783a (2013-01-06 21:10:55 -0800))

In our solution we have several View components (Grid, autocomplete, search views etc.). Some of these components access the store, models etc. so they have a controller that handles that work. These views are used in several templates throughout our solution.

In the old version (pre2) we used those view components like this:

```
App.ConsoleView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'console',
    searchView: App.SearchView.extend(),
    .....
})
```

And in the console template we used the common view like this

```
{{view view.searchView controllerBinding='App.searchController'}}
```

I have always felt that this approach is not the best way, and with the new version of Ember it has smacked us on our fingers :)

Now to the question: 'What is the recommended way to use a shared View in a template which needs a controller.'

In the newer versions of Ember the template expression

```
{{view view.searchView controllerBinding='App.searchController'}}
```

does not work because App.searchController is no longer instantiated at the App namespace.

I have thought of some choices but really don't like them.

1. I could connect the controller to the 'parent controller' through
   the router, but then I would have to do this in every route where I
   use a shared component, and that would be a lot.
2. I could fetch the controller through some hacky way and set it through the init function in the views init function.

Does someone have any recommendations on how to do this a good way? I cannot find any documentation on this, and have run out of googlejuize.

All responses will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would try to use {{render "search"}}, it will lookup the searchController, then instantiate a SearchView and connect them.

Otherwise, I know there are currently discussion in order to beeing able to pass a controller class in the view helper. But not implemented yet.

Update: For now, I would perhaps use the second solution you propose, using https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/ext/controller.js#L33

```
App.ParentView = Ember.View.extend({
  searchView = Ember.View.extend({
    init: function(){
      this._super();
      this.set('controller', this.get('parentView.controller').controllerFor('search'))
    }
  })
})
```

Here I assume that all search view will share the same controller (and its underlying application state).

Comment: Great! hadn't seen that helper. :) Sometimes I need to use the same view several times in the same template, but with different parameters. And I see that the render helper have an Ember.assert("This view is already rendered"... ) Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I think you want each view having its own controller too, right ? The related discussion is here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1637

Comment: @TommyKey I've updated the answer... but this will not work if you need a different instance for each controller :s

Comment: Tnx, that is the current workaround that we implemented, to get it from the parentView.controller. Will probably go for the Ember.controllerFor('...') while the ControllerClass is beeing planned and implemented. Good to see that it is some work going on non-singleton controllers too, since I see multiple components in the future that will require this. :)

Comment: Yep, I think this way will be very cool in order to beeing able to more easily create reusable views. For now, Perhaps you can just manage the instantiation by yourself (App.SearchController.create()) in the init method ?

Comment: One more question regarding you answer here. the function your refering: Ember.controllerFor('search') doesn't work? From what I can see the function is defined like this: Ember.controllerFor = function(container, controllerName, context) {...} or did I misunderstand something here?